# Validation of user input or ���������

Tags: php, unicode, filter, validation, detect

We're letting users search a database from a single text input and I'm having difficulties in filtering some user supplied strings.

For example, if the user submits:

```
��������� lcd SONY
```

(Note the ?'s) I need to cancel the search.

I include the base64 encoded version of the above string wrapped up so that its easy run:

```
print(base64_decode("1MfLxc/RwdPHIGxjZCBTT05Z"));
```

I've ignored such inputs before but now (am not sure why) just realised the mysql database query is taking nearly forever to execute so this is now on high priority.

Another example to highlight that we are using utf-8 and mb_detect_encoding is not helping much:

```
print(base64_decode("zqDOm8+Fzr3PhM63z4HOuc6/IM+Bzr/Phc+HzyU="));
ΠΛυντηριο ρουχ�%
```

So:

- how can I detect/filter these inputs?
- how is this input being generated?

Comment: Rejecting these inputs is the wrong thing to do.  You need to figure why they are adversely affecting performance in the first place.

Comment: This is the first line of defence. I'm stuck at the moment so I'll be investigating the database performance issue now until I get a bright idea.

Comment: Are you saying the user is actually manually entering the replacement character?  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FFFD/index.htm

Comment: I have no idea what a 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' is. Is that appearing in the strings I give as examples?

Comment: Yes - did you click the link in my comment?

That character will generally only be inserted by software, not users themselves.

Comment: @Peter What software? In my first example string, I don't see a repetition of the base64 encoded 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER'...?

Comment: I'm viewing Stack Overflow in UTF-8.  Whatever text you copy-pasted into this question, most of it is not valid UTF-8 byte sequences.  Therefore, my browser (Firefox) is replacing those characters in the output with U+FFFD.  If I manually switch to another encoding (via View -> Character Encoding) to a European encoding like Windows 1251, I can see what all seem to be valid characters.

So part of the confusion here is what encoding your data is in.  Do you know?  If you don't, you need to find out.

Comment: When I switch to windows 1251 I see characters but its still garbage. We are expecting utf-8 at all points in our app.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to say, that you have some data that isn't UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be getting that, although if you really want to filter (which I don't reccommend), do a check for alphanumeric as well as "-.;", etc.

You can use some of these functions to help you in the filtering process.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Comment: Does that handle something like "παπουτσια"? No.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute these queries after creating the connection to mysql, it should handle utf-8 input and results just fine without spitting out ?'s.

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $mysqlConn);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $mysqlConn);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $mysqlConn);
```

(assuming the database is set to utf-8 and you don't mind not filtering them if they don't turn into ?'s)

(also assuming you are using mysql, other dbms probably have similar functions)

Comment: We are getting this input from the user before it even touches the database.